# Header layout above TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/NwewaBx.png]

I currently have the above layout without the header implemented. All I need is to figure out how to add the header.

Here is the header layout I want to put above the tabs:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/green">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_image"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hey!"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I use a `RecyclerView` for the content below the tabs. I use 3 different `Fragments` for the `Activity`.

Here is my Activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayout"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is one of my Fragments:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I add the header above the `TabLayout` and keep normal scrolling behaviors?

Comment: FrameLayout might be good for this as you can position it anywhere on screen. So one possible way to achieve this -- No toolbar, and use a framelayout  and put whatever you want inside it including other layouts, position it where you want, and below it the tabls

Comment: Only the content portion of the screen is scrollable with your suggestion. :/

Comment: check this library 
https://github.com/noties/Scrollable

Answer (score 0):

You just need a RecyclerView to do that.
Combine your header and tabLayout to a Header view, then add to your RecyclerView.

Check https://github.com/u3breeze/android-RecyclerView-WithHeaderAndFooter. I did a extension of RecyclerView.Adapter. Easy to add header and footer to RecyclerView.

Comment: Re-read my question and look at the provided image. What you linked isn't what I'm looking for.